# Fast Startup disables shutdown

Tags: windows-8, shutdown

When fast startup option is enabled and I try to shutdown/hibernate,only I am logged out and I am shown the user account login screen. Shutdown works fine when the option is off. Also the

```
shutdown 0
```

works fine when the fast startup option is enabled.
THe hibernate option does not work even when fast startup option is off.
What can be the problem?

Comment: if some more info is required please tell me how to get it.

Comment: I am unable to understand your question. Please clarify